# fastest non-destructive method to get sorted version of a heap?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, heap

I have a priority heap holding an event queue.

I need to dump this out for the user in order, *but without rendering the heap unusable*.

Obviously if I was willing to destroy it I could simply dequeue events until it was empty, and add them in order to my sorted list.  But then of course the heap is gone.  Further, Quicksort is so much faster than a heap sort that I don't have confidence that I can build this sorted list faster than I can make a copy of the heap and sort the copy.

One idea I had was to in fact destroy the heap by dequeueing all its items, but then... replacing the now-empty priority queue with the resulting sorted list, which should maintain the heap property (of cell i being a higher priority than cell i * 2+1 and i * 2+2).  So I'm also wondering whether such a heap would perform better than a regular heap.

The easiest solution is just to copy the heap array, and sort the copy.  But some sorts do a bad job when given sorted or somewhat-sorted data, and I'm wondering whether the Standard C++ library's sort (or C qsort()) could be trusted to handle sorting a heap as efficiently?

Conversely, while quicksort is far faster than heapsort in the general case, this isn't the general case.  The array is already heapified, which is the first half the work of heapsort.  It'd be plausible that pulling the heap items out in order (the second half) could be faster than quicksort.  So I'm wondering if there's a research result that it is faster to 1) copy heapified array, 2) pull items out in order and place at end of copy, and 3) reverse copy, is typically faster than quicksort.  (Or, pull items out in order and place at *second* new array, and use that as your return value.  I suspect the reversal stage may be better than increasing the cache lines needed.)

Comment: Could not you just make a copy of heap before dequeuing all the items ?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that your custom sorting solution would be better than [std::sort_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort_heap)?

Comment: Create an array of indices and operate on the indices.

Comment: To answer `[would such a heap] perform better than a regular heap`, you'd need to specify at least operations to be supported.

Comment: *Do you have any reason to believe that your custom sorting solution would be better than sort_heap?*  - Well, this is primarily a priority queue that only sometimes needs a human-readable output.  I don't think sort_heap supports adding events after heapification.  I need to support random-access cancelling and rescheduling.  (A direct rescheduling operation is much faster than a delete followed by insert.)  I also wanted to make it nearly impervious to accidental misuse which most priority queues seem to be vulnerable to.  So faster safer and maybe less coding than customizing off-the-shelf.

Comment: *Create an array of indices and operate on the indices.* -- It IS an array of indices.  I still don't necessarily want to copy it if I can avoid it, and even after copying there's still the question of best sort.

Comment: *[would such a heap] perform better than a regular heap* --Did you mean to address this to some other question?  I'm not asking about heap performance, where I think I have a good solution.  Instead I'm asking a more general question about creating a fully-ordered vector of objects given a vector partially-ordered with the heap property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're concerned about a performance problem that isn't really a problem. As I understand it, modern C++ implementations of `sort` use Introsort, which avoids the pathological worst-case times of a naïve Quicksort. And the difference between Quicksort and Heapsort, in the context of generating user output, is not large enough to be a concern.

Just copy the heap and sort it. Or sort the heap directly and output the result, provided of course that doing so doesn't break the heap.

You asked if a sorted heap performs better than a non-sorted heap. No. When adding an item, you still add it as the last node and sift it up. Half of the nodes in a heap are at the leaf level and assuming a uniform distribution of new items, then half of the items you add will end up at the leaf level, requiring no swaps. Worst case is if every item you add ends up being the smallest (in a min-heap), in which case every time you add an item it will take log(n) swaps to move it to the root. Now, if every item added is larger than any other item in the heap, then of course addition is O(1). But that's true regardless of whether the heap was initially created from a sorted array.

Deleting an item from the heap requires that you replace the root item with an item from the leaf level and then sift it down. In a sorted heap, the likelihood that the replacement item will end up back down at the leaf level is very high, which means that adjusting the heap will require the maximum log(n) swaps. A sorted heap *almost guarantees* that removal will require the maximum number of swaps. In this case, a sorted heap is potentially *worse* in terms of performance than a heap constructed from a randomly-arranged array.

But all that changes quickly as you begin adding items to and removing items from the heap. The heap becomes "not sorted" fairly quickly.

Over the life of the priority queue, it's highly unlikely that the initial order of items will make any noticeable difference in the performance of your binary heap.

Comment: *You asked if a sorted heap performs better than a non-sorted heap. No.* -- to be clear I didn't mean to be asking that, but whether a heapified array could sort faster than a random array.  EG, was there a known research finding that copying the heapified array, pulling items out in order and placing them in a third array, might possibly be faster than a full qsort, since we skip the stage of having to heapify.  Sure I can time it myself but interested more as much as the general theory as opposed to my specific case.

Comment: *A sorted heap almost guarantees that removal will require the maximum number of swaps.* -- Interesting and important insight for case of new items having equal chance to be anywhere in the tree.  I use priority queues for timer event queues, and typically have many slow timers, (e.g., once a day) and several super-fast timers (e.g. once every 10ms or sec).  Over the course of the day, the fast repeating timers dominate, so instead of delete and new insert, I write a "change time" method that often doesn't move a timer at all.  1x O(1) instead of 2x (logn).

Answer (score 1):

With the usual heap implementation, just sort the heap in place.  A sorted list satisfies the heap condition for a min-heap.  Alternately if you sort the heap descending, you satisfy the heap condition for a max-heap.  And you can always sort it one way and traverse another if that is what you need.

Note that the `sort::heap` documentation warns about breaking the heap condition.  Be careful that you know you haven't if you are changing the heap data in place.